# get chance to do something when my app was killed

Tags: java, android, wifi

I have an android app . User can get wifi password nearby using my app, then could connect to wifi network.

But if user kill my app after connected to wifi, my app have no chance to get notification, and user can still using wifi .   How could I resolve the problem cause I want to know who is using my wifi and get the networktraffic of every user.  In some mobile phone, user can kill ererything about the app include service, this make me confused.   Please, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something you can easily work around. If someone uninstalls your application or kills it, there's nothing you can do to start it again without their permission (there will always be a single point of failure).

If you want to monitor usage, there are many tools available that probably have the feature you're looking for. [this](https://superuser.com/questions/54549/how-can-i-monitor-internet-usage-in-my-network) question on SU has a great list of tools that you could look into. Monitoring network traffic by MAC address on a system *you* control is fairly robust. Monitoring on a system that you *don't* control is not, and never will be.

Comment: Is it easy to program route on android to monitor the wifi user and network traffic? If it is not too complicated , I think it is a way to do my thing.

Comment: Could you clarify your use case a bit more? What do you want to monitor? Why do you want to monitor it? Do you *have* to monitor on the client-side (again, this will always be unreliable compared to monitoring server-side)?

Comment: I want use my app to monitor user's wifi when they are using my wifi.  I really think it is a unresolved problem. Since app will be killed and user can still connecting to the wifi

Comment: Right, and I'm telling you that you cannot resolve this. If the user or system kills your app (for example, Android is low on memory), you will *not* be able to monitor the usage.

You need to take a different approach, like the one suggested in my answer. Don't monitor traffic on the users device, monitor it on the router, or between your router and your modem. I use the tomato firmware to accomplish this. See here: http://www.nextgendigitalhome.com/2127/home-network/scalable-gateway/using-the-tomato-firmware-to-monitor-bandwidth-by-ip-address/

Comment: You can also use additional features with Tomato, such as blocking users after they hit a configurable usage.